# .scroll() not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `jQuery` to check if a `div` is scrolled. It works on `window`, But it is not working on specific div.

**Works fine:**

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log('scroll happened');
 });
```

**Not Wokring Fine:**

```
$('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes').scroll(function(){ 
    console.log('scroll happened');
});
```

**HTML**
I am using ERIC Hynds Multiselect. So scroll is present on its `ul` with class `ui-multiselect-checkboxes`. You can see live example [here](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm)

Comment: please try the solution i gave you , i tried and it works

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.ui-multiselect-checkboxes', function(){ 
    console.log('scroll happened');
});
```

This is because these elements are dynamically created by multiselect plugin.

Comment: It is not working dear. Even I have checked by changing document to body.

Comment: Have you written this code in document ready handler. If not, please do

Answer (score 1):

create **delegate** event because these are created dynamically by youe multiselect plugin.

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.ui-multiselect-checkboxes', function(){ 
    console.log('scroll happened');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes').bind('scroll',chk_scroll);
});


function chk_scroll(e)
{
    var elem = $(e.currentTarget);
    if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) 
    {
        console.log("Scrolled");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
<script>
$(function() {
     $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes").on('scroll', function () { 
       console.log('scroll happened'); 
      });
});
</script>
```

//OH I CHECKED ITS WORKING. Now

Just check place all files you have in header of this HTML ,just Create a folder and place files accordingly inside "jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files" FOLDER

And then check console
//NEW  SOLUTION

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0078)http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery.multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/prettify.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/prettify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery MultiSelect Widget Demo_files/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect();
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="test" onLoad="prettyPrint();" cz-shortcut-listen="true">

<h2>Basic Demos</h2>

<p>Both multiselects are created with the following one-liner.  Optgroup support is built in out of the box:</p>
<pre class="prettyprint"><span class="pln">$</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="kwd">function</span><span class="pun">(){</span><span class="pln"><br>&nbsp; &nbsp;$</span><span class="pun">(</span><span class="str">"select"</span><span class="pun">).</span><span class="pln">multiselect</span><span class="pun">();</span><span class="pln"> <br></span><span class="pun">});</span></pre>

<h3>Basic</h3>
<p>
    <select title="Basic example" multiple="multiple" name="example-basic" size="5" style="display: none;">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option10">Option 10</option>
    <option value="option11">Option 11</option>
    <option value="option12">Option 12</option>
    </select><button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Basic example" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 225px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>Select options</span></button>
</p>

<h3>With Optgroups</h3>
<p>Click on an optgroup's heading to toggle the checked state of the entire group.</p>
<p>
    <select name="example-optgroup" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="display: none;">
    <optgroup label="Group One">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group Two">
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
        <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select><button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 225px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>Select options</span></button>
</p>



<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 217px;"><div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-multiselect-header ui-helper-clearfix"><ul class="ui-helper-reset"><li><a class="ui-multiselect-all" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span><span>Check all</span></a></li><li><a class="ui-multiselect-none" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span>Uncheck all</span></a></li><li class="ui-multiselect-close"><a href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#" class="ui-multiselect-close"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span></a></li></ul></div><ul class="ui-multiselect-checkboxes ui-helper-reset"><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-0" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-0" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option1" title="Option 1"><span>Option 1</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-1" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-1" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option2" title="Option 2"><span>Option 2</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-2" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-2" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option3" title="Option 3"><span>Option 3</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-3" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-3" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option4" title="Option 4"><span>Option 4</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-4" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-4" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option5" title="Option 5"><span>Option 5</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-5" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-5" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option6" title="Option 6"><span>Option 6</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-6" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-6" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option7" title="Option 7"><span>Option 7</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-7" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-7" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option8" title="Option 8"><span>Option 8</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-8" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-8" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option9" title="Option 9"><span>Option 9</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-9" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-9" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option10" title="Option 10"><span>Option 10</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-10" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-10" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option11" title="Option 11"><span>Option 11</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-0-option-11" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-0-option-11" name="multiselect_0" type="checkbox" value="option12" title="Option 12"><span>Option 12</span></label></li></ul></div><div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 217px;"><div class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-multiselect-header ui-helper-clearfix"><ul class="ui-helper-reset"><li><a class="ui-multiselect-all" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span><span>Check all</span></a></li><li><a class="ui-multiselect-none" href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span>Uncheck all</span></a></li><li class="ui-multiselect-close"><a href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#" class="ui-multiselect-close"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span></a></li></ul></div><ul class="ui-multiselect-checkboxes ui-helper-reset"><li class="ui-multiselect-optgroup-label "><a href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#">Group One</a></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-2-option-0" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-2-option-0" name="multiselect_2" type="checkbox" value="option1" title="Option 1"><span>Option 1</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-2-option-1" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-2-option-1" name="multiselect_2" type="checkbox" value="option2" title="Option 2"><span>Option 2</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-2-option-2" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-2-option-2" name="multiselect_2" type="checkbox" value="option3" title="Option 3"><span>Option 3</span></label></li><li class="ui-multiselect-optgroup-label "><a href="http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/basic.htm#">Group Two</a></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-2-option-3" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-2-option-3" name="multiselect_2" type="checkbox" value="option4" title="Option 4"><span>Option 4</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-2-option-4" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-2-option-4" name="multiselect_2" type="checkbox" value="option5" title="Option 5"><span>Option 5</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-2-option-5" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-2-option-5" name="multiselect_2" type="checkbox" value="option6" title="Option 6"><span>Option 6</span></label></li><li class=" "><label for="ui-multiselect-2-option-6" title="" class="ui-corner-all"><input id="ui-multiselect-2-option-6" name="multiselect_2" type="checkbox" value="option7" title="Option 7"><span>Option 7</span></label></li></ul></div><div class="ugdv_contextMenu" id="ugdv_myMenu" style="display: none;"><ul id="ugdv_contextMenu"><li id="ugdv_menuItem_google_docs">Open in Google Docs Viewer</li><li id="ugdv_menuItem_new_tab">Open link in new tab</li><li id="ugdv_menuItem_new_window">Open link in new window</li><li id="ugdv_menuItem_new_incognito">Open link in new incognito window</li><li class="ugdv_seperator"></li><li id="ugdv_menuItem_download_file">Download file</li><li id="ugdv_menuItem_copy">Copy link address</li><li id="ugdv_menuItem_editpdf">Edit PDF File on PDFescape.com</li></ul></div><div id="ugdv_jqContextMenu" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 9999;"></div><div style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute; opacity: 0.2; z-index: 9998; display: none;"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
$('ul').click(function(){
var className=$(this).attr("class");
});

     $("."+className).on('scroll', function () { 
       console.log('scroll happened'); 
      });
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: Should i also Explain, the logic behind it?/

Comment: you have added class class to select manually but in my case it is created dynamically

Comment: Name the class you are talking about?

Comment: ui-multiselect-checkboxes class is added dynamically. As I am only adding select box and populate it on open event

Comment: I have it working by calling the scroll function inside its beforeOpen event. So its working with it. According to your method it will not work. Thanks for your time